# Thread is not being removed when removing event handler in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events

I'm developing some code to detect new files in a directory and signal it in a new thread through the Created event of FileSystemWatcher. While testing this I noticed that after I removed the eventhandler from the event the thread that was being used was not closed. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong when I'm removing the eventhandler?

My code looks like this:

```
Private fileSystemWatcher As FileSystemWatcher
Private fileSystemEventHandler As New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf UpdateSomething)
Private isStopping As Boolean

Private Sub NewThread()
    fileSystemWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher("C:\Temp")
    fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.xml"
    fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = False
    fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
    AddHandler fileSystemWatcher.Created, fileSystemEventHandler
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateSomething(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "UpdateSomething"
    Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = False
    RemoveHandler fileSystemWatcher.Created, fileSystemEventHandler
    fileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    fileSystemWatcher = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf NewThread)
    thread.Name = "NewThread"
    thread.Start()
End Sub
```

So first I start off clicking Button 2 to start the event handler. I copy a xml file to the Temp folder and the event will trigger and set the name of the thread. After that I will click Button 1 to remove the event handler. If I then pause the execution the Thread "UpdateSomething" will still be there. Can someone explain why?

Comment: You don't need to start a new thread to use FileSystemWatcher...

Comment: No I know that. But I want to. I want the main thread to handle other parts.

Comment: the FileSystemWatcher events are already raised on another thread, so there is absolutely no benefit in creating a new thread explicitly.

Comment: When I ran my code without raising another thread it would actually raise on the main thread.

Comment: I just tried and the event is raised on a different thread. The only case where it is raised on the main thread is if you set the SynchronizingObject property.

Comment: Yeah I ran it now and you're right. The last time I must have set the SynchronizingObject. Thanks

Comment: But my question is still relevant as the thread that will raise the event will still be there even if you remove the event handler.

Comment: What do you mean by "be there" ? It's a thread from the ThreadPool, so it will always be there, even if it's not doing anything

Comment: Yes but if I remove the event handler and dispose the FileSystemWatcher object, why is the thread not exiting? What is the thread doing or waiting for?

Comment: The thread just returns to the thread pool and remains available to perform other tasks. Read about the [ThreadPool class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I thought I will close it any way. As @thomas-levesque wrote it’s because of the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

When you press Button1, UpdateSomething is no longer called when you add an xml file to the temp folder. That means it has succesfully removed the event handler. However, an instance of the handler could still be running. Removing an event handler only disconnects the function from the event. If the thread is still active, you should be able to terminate it using Thread.cancelJob.